# Creating a location overlay on a MapView by pushing a button

Tags: android, location

Currently, my app has a mapview that creates a `new MyLocationOverlay` in the `onCreate` function.

```
locationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, map);
locationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(centerAroundFix);
map.getOverlays().add(locationOverlay);
```

I'm trying to create a button that does this optionally, much like google maps.  This is what I have so far.

```
ImageButton locButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.googlemaps_select_location);

locButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        locationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(ctx, map);
        locationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(centerAroundFix);
        map.getOverlays().add(locationOverlay);
    }
});
```

The only thing I had to change was the 'this' to 'ctx'.  I set `ctx = this` in the `onCreate()` function.  I've also tried using `getApplicationContext()` instead of `ctx`

Using the debugger, I break on the `onClick()` function and can step through it.  After hitting run, I telnet to the emulator and use the `geo fix` command to issue a fix to the emulator.  Unfortunately, `centerAroundFix()` is never called.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong, here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by moving
`locationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(ctx, map)`
to the `onCreate()` function.

Perhaps `locationOverlay` get garbage collected if it's inside the `onClick()` function?